# Solution singular PDE

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, calculus-of-variations

I've been studying the following singular PDE
$$
\mathrm{div}\left(\left(1+\frac{|\nabla g|}{|\nabla f|}\right)\nabla f\right)=0$$

in $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{2}$. 
Do you know any reference, where this kind of singularity has been studied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume for simplicity that $g$ is linear. Then the integrand $|\nabla f|^2 + const.|\nabla f|$ is smooth and uniformly convex (as a function of $\nabla f$) except at the origin. It is known that the minimizers of such functionals are at least $C^1$-regular.

Indeed, if $f$ minimizes $\int F(\nabla f)$ and $F$ is smooth and uniformly convex away from some bounded set $E$, then it is known that for $x \in \Omega$ the gradients $\nabla f(B_r(x))$ localize as $r \rightarrow 0$ either to the convex hull $K_E$ of $E$, or to a point outside $K_E$. See the result of Colombo-Figalli here:

http://cvgmt.sns.it/media/doc/paper/1996/c1deg_final.pdf

In your case $E = K_E$ is a single point, so $f$ is $C^1$.

Addendum: The idea of the above result is that ellipticity kicks in as soon as $|\nabla f| > 0$. The argument is based on applying linear estimates to each derivative $\partial_kf$ of $f$. These solve the linearized Euler-Lagrange equation $\text{div}(D^2F(\nabla f) \nabla \partial_k f) = 0$, which is uniformly elliptic when $\partial_k f > 0$. The De Giorgi-Nash-Moser theorem gives continuity of solutions to such equations.

When $|\nabla g|$ is not constant I expect the result is still true provided e.g. $g \in C^{1,1}$. Indeed, for the more general case $F(\nabla f,\,x)$ the equation for $\partial_kf$ has the right hand side $-\partial_i(F_{p_ix_k}(\nabla f,\,x))$. If $f_k > 0$ then uniformly elliptic estimates give continuity of solutions provided $F_{px}$ is e.g. bounded (or even $L^{\gamma}$ for some $\gamma > 2$, since you are in $\mathbb{R}^2$). In your case $|F_{px}| = |\nabla |\nabla g||$, so if $|D^2g|$ is bounded (or $g \in W^{2,\,\gamma}$ for some $\gamma > 2$) it seems similar arguments may work.

Comment: Thanks! Do you think the result still holds if $\nabla g$ is not constant? In the reference you indicated, the function F only depends on $\nabla f$, do you know if the result extends to functions F depending also on the variable $x\in \Omega$?

Comment: I believe the result should still hold when e.g. $g \in W^{2,\,\gamma}$ for some $\gamma > 2$- the answer is updated with some heuristics for this.

Comment: Last question: do you think it is reasonable to hope for some sort of interior estimates? I mean, do you expect it will be possible to bound the $C^1$ norm of the minimizer, say in a ball, in terms of its boundary value?

Comment: If $g \in W^{2,\,\gamma}$ for some $\gamma > 2$ (or $\gamma > n$ in $n$ dimensions) then De Giorgi-Nash-Moser theory gives an interior estimate for $\|\nabla f\|_{L^{\infty}}$ in terms of $\|f\|_{H^1}$ and $\|D^2g\|_{L^{\gamma}}$, since the equation for e.g. the positive part of $\partial_kf - 1$ is non-degenerate. I suspect that one can then get an interior estimate for the modulus of continuity of $\nabla f$ by modifying the ideas from the indicated reference.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if similar techniques are available for systems, that is if I let also g vary? I would like to have a priori estimate that guarantees that f and g are at least Lipschitz. Am I hoping too much? I knew of De Giorgi/Nach-Moser theory, but I believed it applied only to uniformly elliptic PDEs. Do you have a reference that covers also the singular case?

Comment: Two comments: First, De Giorgi-Nash-Moser does only apply to uniformly elliptic PDE. The point is that when $\max\{\partial_k f - 1,\,0\} > 0$ the coefficients of its equation are uniformly elliptic ($|\nabla f| \geq 1$ there), and where it equals zero the coefficients play no role so we can replace them e.g. by $\delta_{ij}$ on that set if we like. (The indicated reference uses this observation).

Comment: About systems, I am not sure. To apply the above, one would need to say that a minimizing map $(f,\,g)$ of the energy $E(f,\,g) = \int (|\nabla f| + |\nabla g|)^2$ is in $W^{2,\,\gamma}$ for some $\gamma > 2$, which in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is already a $C^{1,\,\alpha}$ estimate. Since the integrand is neither uniformly convex or has bounded second derivatives as a function of $(\nabla f,\, \nabla g)$ (which would give such an estimate, see ``reverse Holder theory") it seems one would need to use its special structure to say anything in this direction.